# JSON substituindo informação com o mesmo nome

Tags: json, node.js, fs

Quero gravar dois ou mais nomes em um arquivo JSON. Porém, quando tento fazer, isso ele salva apenas a última informação.

Minha função:

```
async function grava_login(){                          
 fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify({name: "Mohamed Almaci",
name:"Masq"}),"utf8", async function(err){    
 try{                                                    
  if(err){                                                
   console.log(err);                                     
  }                                                      
  else{                                                   
   console.log("The file was saved!");                   
  }                                                     
 }                                                      
 catch{                                                  
  console.log("Erro ao salvar dados no arquivo json!")
 }
})}
```

**Como quero que o JSON fique:**

```
{ 
  "name": "Mohamed almaci",
  "name": "Masq"
}
```

**Como o JSON está:**

```
{
  "name":"Masq"
}
```

Comment: Voce está sobreescrevendo o `name` ao fazer `name="Masq"`. Se voce atribuir outra chave, por exemplo `name1: "Masq"` , ele nao vai sobreescrever e entao vai ser salvo todo o objeto `{ 
  name: "Mohamed almaci",
  name1: "Masq"
}` no arquivo.

Comment: Percebi que estou sobreescrevendo porém vi gente fazendo do jeito que quero e funcionando, vi um exemplo mais era com email, e a pessoa conseguiu fazer o mesmo que quero, porém não era com node e era sobre outro tema então não consegui entender como fazer isso pelo node js com a lib fs.

Comment: Olhe este vídeo de exemplo https://youtu.be/iiADhChRriM minuto 8:44 perceba que ele usou name duas vezes, mas não consigo fazer isto. Já tentei de tudo quanto é forma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guilherme,

Para salvar um JSON com duas propriedades `name`, você pode criar um array e cada posição do array ser um objeto que contém a propriedade `name` e seu respectivo valor, exemplo:

```
[
  {
    "name":"Mohamed Almaci"
  },
  {
    "name":"Masq"
  }
]
```

Inclusive, no [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iiADhChRriM&feature=youtu.be&t=524) que você citou (8:44), ele segue essa ideia.

---

Com isso, seu código ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
const fs = require("fs");

async function grava_login() {
  fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify([{name: "Mohamed Almaci"},{name:"Masqx"}])
    , "utf8", async function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log("The file was saved!");
    }
  });
}

grava_login();
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/IvoryBruisedMachinecodeinstruction

Comment: :) não tinha usado o [ tinha tentado com chaves sem criar o array, obrigado.

Comment: Só não entendi o porquê no arquivo json dele não ficou com o [ e o meu ficou, mais funcionou!